# How to control Kubernetes Nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm looking to create a serverless like architecture in GKE (a job may use 3000-4000 nodes, typically it'll be 60-180). Each `Pod` in this system needs access to a GPU. Someone suggested I create 1 `Pod` inside 1 `Node` and have that act as a "function".

I could use `n1-standard-1` with `1 x NVIDIA Tesla T4`. Im stuck figuring out how I can manage all these `Nodes`. I am familiar with creating node-pools via `gcloud` something like this `gcloud container node-pools create gpu-pool --num-nodes=1 --accelerator type=nvidia-tesla-t4,count=1 --zone us-central1-a --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --cluster k8s-gpu`

What I am not sure of is how do I create an ephemeral `Node` with a defined `Pod` (custom image, etc) from an external trigger? With Lambda I can trigger functions via API gateway. I'm looking for something similar, i.e a 1:1 mapping between trigger and creating a `Node`.

This way in my job I can decide I need 100 workers and issue them via HTTP. Does this even make sense, are there any improvements to this approach?

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create nodes until your job runs, you can use [cluster autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler) to act (add/remove GPU node for the node pool) according to your request/workloads.

Comment: Ive heard of https://keda.sh/... I need to create a `Node` per specified job, not reply on traffic or CPU metrics. Im looking for more control if that makes sense? I see in the autoscaler I can set a `min` and `max` but lets say I have a job that needs 100 `Nodes` specifically how can I issue the autoscaler to handle `n` jobs

Comment: If not mistaken you want to run a job that needs thousands of GPU which resulted to equal number of nodes. Obviously, you don't want to start so many pods/nodes until you really needs it. In this case, `keda` won't help here because keda does not react to pending pod. See this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus) for implementation details.

Comment: I have a video rendering service which renders 60 frames a second. I issue a node.js process on GPU per 1 second of video and run however many seconds in parallel. So if a video is 30s it would be 30 Nodes needed (they require GPUs). The number of Nodes is n. A 1 hour video could use 1000+ Nodes, but 60-180 are most common. Each Node.js server takes 20-30s to render 60 frames, so they're long running.

Comment: Maybe autoscaler will see a Node is busy and create a new one?

Comment: No. First, your app cannot share GPU. If you must process all frames in parallel you have no choice but start equal number of GPU nodes for the number of frames. In this case, you deploy as many pods as you need (assumed 1 pod 1 frame thus 1 node). Your node pool will not have that many nodes so those pods will enter pending state - this is where autoscaler comes in and scale up your node pool size. When the pods are terminated, autoscaler then scale down your node pool size so nodes don't sit on the bench burning your wallet.

Comment: Right, my questions is how to dynamically deploy as many pods as I need. Its 1 pod per 60 frames BTW

Comment: Given a video, how many pods are needed is up to your app to figure out. With that number there are many ways to start the workload. ie. you can emit a `Job` spec and apply it on the fly using `kubectl`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246392/discussion-between-michael-joseph-aubry-and-gohmc).

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.
@MichaelJosephAubry

Comment: I still haven't fully figured it out, the autoscaler is cool, but I was looking for manual control over how many nodes were created.